# Implementing a jQuery animated form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Java and its modules and believe I have followed the instructions I have found to make this animated form and others run, yet I can't seem to make them work.

For the main sign-up form I'm using an template from https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz/ and, after modifying the text a little, copied the elements to three files : /test.php - /index_style.css and javascript.js

The following codes are what I have :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flight One | Flying Passion</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/index_style.css" style="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/CSS/styles.less" />
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.0/less.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="/US/en/local/Ressources/Java/javascript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="msform">
                                    <!-- progressbar -->
                                  <ul id="progressbar">
                                    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
                                    <li>Social Profiles</li>
                                    <li>Personal Details</li>
                                  </ul>
                                  <!-- fieldsets -->
                                  <fieldset>
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
                                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                                    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
                                    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                                    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                                  </fieldset>
                                  <fieldset>
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
                                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
                                    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
                                    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
                                    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
                                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
                                    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                                  </fieldset>
                                  <fieldset>
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
                                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
                                    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
                                    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                                    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
                                  </fieldset>
                                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the CSS code I copied exactly as it is in the template and inserted the exact same java script into my javascript.js file.

When I use simple java functions like "upperCaseF(this)" it runs from the linked file but non of the other functions..

I have really looked around for a solution and still don't understand why it would run on their emulator but not on my side.

I'm using Sublime Text and MAMP but even when I upload it to my website it doesn't work either...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you check if there are any errors in your javascript console (in Chrome, press F12 and click on the tab 'Console')? What error messages are being displayed (if there are any)?

Comment: Yes I get this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at javascript.js:7

Comment: Starting at line 7 I have :

$(".next").click(function() {

Comment: You are trying to use jQuery before it's actually loaded.  The script, `<script src="/US/en/local/Ressources/Java/javascript.js"></script>`, should be the last `<script>` in the `<head>`.  Unless you aren't using a ready listener, then it should be the last thing in the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading your jquery code before you loaded the framework.

Your Header should look like this:

```
    <head>
    <title>Flight One | Flying Passion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/index_style.css" style="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/CSS/styles.less" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.0/less.min.js" ></script>
    <!-- TODO Verify what version of jquery is needed -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO Verify what version of jquery is needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- loading custom jquery code here -->
    <script src="/US/en/local/Ressources/Java/javascript.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Also, you should add a ready event to your custom code (in this case, because you are loading it in the header tag) like this (if you haven't already done so):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // TODO Add your jQuery code in here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! Yes I needed to put it at then end of the <body>... I'm not sure why this information is hard to find online. Thanks again for your help !

Comment: I would like to add, that it looks like you are loading 2 different jQuery versions. It is loading 3.3.1 from googleapi.com and then loading 2.1.3 from cloudflare. You might want to double check.

Comment: I deleted the 2.1.3 version. It was just my disparate self trying to figure out how to run it... Cheers